# Am I right about finding a vector's component along a normalized vector?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm doing some programming and I'm writing a little math library to speed things up and make things more readable. I know the very basics of linear algebra but I want to learn more. Right now, my issue is that I'm not sure if my function for returning a vector's component along a normal vector is correct.

For the sake of clarity, in case I'm getting the terminology wrong, if I had a vector (7, 5, 3) and performed this operation on it with the normal vector being (1, 0, 0), I would like it to return (7, 0, 0), the magnitude of the vector along the X axis. I want to be sure my function can do this with any given unit vector, not just the coordinate system's basis. By subtracting the output vector from the input vector, I should have a vector that lies on the plane defined by the normal vector.

Here's what I have:

$$
f(V, N) = \vec V ·\hat N(\hat N)
$$

where V is an arbitrary vector and N is a unit vector.

This is implemented as the expression `vector.Dot(normal) * normal;` in my code, where `Dot()` is just an extension method for the vector struct that computes its dot product with another vector.

What's confusing me is that, when looking into this, I find this function instead:

$$
f(V, N) = \frac{\vec V ⋅ \vec N} {|N|}
$$

from pages like this: [Find the component of $\vec{a}$ along $\vec{b}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/286391/find-the-component-of-veca-along-vecb)

I don't understand what the difference is, as long as N is always a unit vector. In my software my version of the function seems to work just fine, but I'm worried I might be missing something important. If someone could walk me through the reasoning behind the 2nd one, I would be very grateful!

Comment: You are doing it correctly, it's just a matter of terminology. A vector being normal usually refers to it being perpendicular to some surface. A vector of length 1 is said to be normalized.  What you found is a vector that is the projection of $\vec V$ in the direction defined by $vec N$ where you assume $\vec N$ is normalized, "component" generally refers to the norm of the projection.

Comment: Ah, I see! Thank you all for clearing up the terminology, I'm really thankful and I'm glad to know that I was on the right track and that my understanding of how the dot product works is somewhat solid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second expression the scaling $N/|N|$ is just $N$ when $N$ is a normal vector, so the calculation is essentially the same.

The first version of $f$ returns a vector of the length you want in the direction you want. The second version of $f$ returns just the length of that vector.

Comment: Ah, so that's why you would use the second function instead of getting the magnitude of the first function's return value, since it simplifies the calculation and would require less expensive operations (division instead of square root)?

Comment: If you know you have a unit $N$ then neither requires a square root or a division. If you need to normalize then both do. (You should say $N$ is a unit vector, not a normal vector. "Normal" means perpendicular to something.) Note too that in the second case the "magnitude" can be negative. In the first case there's no need to specify the sign. In both cases the sign tells you (roughly speaking) whether the angle between $N$ and $V$ is acute or obtuse.